# Video from VFR Image Sequence

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-camera, frame-rate

I am using `ffmpeg` to create video from an image sequence that is taken from the Android `Camera`'s `PreviewCallback` method `onPreviewFrame`...

The images are written to a pipe that is connected to `ffmpeg`'s `stdin` using the command :

`ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -f flv -vcodec libx264 <output_file>`

The problem that's arising is that the output video is very short as compared to the actual recording time and all of the frames are shown very rapidly...

But when the frame size is set to the lowest supported preview size, the video appears to be in sync with the actual recording time...

As far as I reckon this seems to be an issue related to the frame rate of the input image sequence and that of the output video...

But the main problem is that the frames that are generated from `onPreviewFrame` are of variable rates...

Is there any way to construct a smooth video from an image sequence having variable frame rate...?

Also, the image sequence is muxed with audio from the microphone which also appears to be out of sync with the video...

Could the video generated using the above process and audio from the microphone be muxed in perfect synchronization...?

Comment: I have compiled ffmpeg using the `Android NDK` into a binary...
I know there is no way to input images as VFR...But is there any way to sync the video frame and audio based ont timestamps using `ffmpeg`...?

Comment: The preview images are written to a pipe that is connected to `ffmpeg`'s `stdin` using the command `ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -f flv -vcodec libx264 <output_file>`...The basic purpose of all this is to create a streamable video...

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question to include all those (important) details. I haven't used it on Android yet, but I would suggest using the actual FFmpeg API to stream the video right from the code, or possibly with another (lower latency) encoder library such as XviD.

Comment: Have edited the question...And using the `FFmpeg command line` saves all the troubles of writing down `JNI` code to interact with the `FFmpeg API`...

Comment: Can you say have you solved this problem?